# Alternatives to Boost::Function and Boost::Bind

Tags: c++, function, boost, callback

Does anyone know of any libraries that can be used in place of Boost::Function and Boost::Bind? We are trying to remove our dependency on Boost since it's a pretty large library. We're looking for something more focused.

I found this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/fastdelegate2.aspx

I've never used it though and it looks like it was last updated in 2007. Has anyone used it?

We use callbacks are fair amount throughout our code and boost::function and boost::bind allow us to do so. But we've run into problems turning RTTI and exceptions off using Boost. So any replacements would need to be usable with RTTI and exceptions turned off.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `std::function` and `std::bind` :-)

Comment: Isn't that C++11? I should have been a little clearer. We're still on C++03.

Comment: I can't remember if I used fastdelegate or just evaluated it, as it was a couple of years ago. However, I thought it was a good option.

Comment: @alk3ovation : Boost is not a library, it is a collection of libraries. Boost.Bind and Boost.Function are extremely _small_ libraries -- why not extract them with [bcp](http://www.boost.org/tools/bcp/) and stick with what works?

Comment: @alk3ovation: You may find `std::tr1::function` and `std::tr1::bind` in `<tr1/functional>`; that's been part of popular compilers for quite some time now.

Comment: @ildjarn: Right, that's not a bad option and one I may end up revisting.

Comment: some of these comments should be answers

Comment: If you use only `boost::bind` and `boost::function`, the size of additional libraries (as in `.so`/`.dll` files) you need is exactly zero. It's all template code in the headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation that you pointed to is built upon undefined behavior according to the standards. Disabling exceptions should be no problem with Boost.Function, as long as you define your own throw_exception function. And I'm sure disabling RTTI won't be a problem either, since Boost.Function goes through great trouble to avoid virtual functions at all (its all explained in its rationale). There are problems with disabling exceptions and RTTI for some Boost libraries, but Function and Bind are not the case, I have been using them in Android NDK with disabled exceptions and RTTI for a long while.

As for alternatives, you could always use the now standard C++11 ones (based on Boost) which are already available in several compilers; or you could always roll your own. There is also an alternative implementation of Boost.Function by Domagoj Saric, but I cannot seem to find pointers to it right now.

Check out Boost bcp tool, to extract only the files related to Function and Bind, and roll on your own version of them. You shouldn't need to change anything for them to work.

Comment: NDK is where we plan on using them. As far as defining your own throw_exception function, where's the best place to do that?

Comment: In a header file of its own that's get `include`d by any other file in the project, before anything else.

Comment: Is this error a result of not having done that: bad codegen, pointer diff in __ZN5boost9exceptionC2Ev to global weak symbol __ZTVN5boost9exceptionE for architecture i386

Comment: I've tried defining throw_exception in one of my .h files. I included it first in the .mm file (trying to get Boost to compile without exceptions and rtti in our iOS project first) but I still get the linker error I stated above. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I've had good results using the [sigslot](http://sigslot.sourceforge.net/) library.  This is an extremely lightweight library, it consists of just a single header file. It plays nice with STL and has optional multithreading support for Windows threads and pthreads.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **bcp** tool which allows you to copy the part of boost library that you need.

There is no need to find alternatives for boost. This is a great library. If any library exists there it is the best in the world. Probably there are some exceptions like boost.test, but in generally it's true. Particularly it's true for boost.function and for boost.bind.